# Add, Subtract, Multiply 2 int Arrays

Tags: c#

C# Assignment.
Basically, I need to make a program to add, subtract , multiply 2 arrays.
For example:

- I accept strings of digits, such as `"12345"` `"54321"`.
- I need to show its sum, difference, and product using arrays...

Example:

```
Input: "12345" "54321"
Output:
   SUM= 66666
   DIFFERENCE= 41976
   PRODUCT= 670592745
```

Comment: Well, if you're talking about "difference" that's going to be interesting when you've got more than two items... but where are you stuck? Do you know how to parse the strings to integers? Do you know how to add numbers together? Where does functional programming (in your tag) come in?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say how you get the string-numbers (i.e "12234") in the input(read from file maybe? or stdin?), but inorder to convert them to integers, use the following:

```
int x = Int32.Parse("12345");
```

or this:

```
int x;
Int32.TryParse("12345", out x);
```

the last one gives you error-free solution, since some strings cannot be converted to int (like ",/.,.,/"), so `TryParse` returns false in this case.

that makes an integer out of a string.

Now, for adding, subtracting and such, you can apply the regular operators of `+`,`-`,..